# simplest way to put an item in an asyncio.Queue from sync code running in a separate thread

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.8

Python complains that  `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Queue.put' was never awaited`

I have searched and seen that a library like [Janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus) exists to solve such a problem. But on 3.8 does there exist a better way?

update. I was able to use create_task to put the item in the queue but it's either blocking on `get` or `put` until some other async event occurs in the system before it stops blocking even though there should now be an item in the queue for it not to need to block. Any ideas why that could be happening? It takes about 10-20s before it automatically unblocks itself but if i send another event it immediately unblocks on the previous event and yet there will be a delay for the current one just the same unless i send another event through.

Comment: Show your code.  Please

Comment: @Pynchia kind of hard to post python code with the indenting issues.

Comment: *kind of hard to post python code with the indenting issues* - What do you mean? People post Python code in questions on the [python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) all the time.

Comment: @user4815162342 yeah i knew about the inline back ticks and using 4 spaces but i dont want to do that for every line/function of code i post, esp with python where whitespace is syntax and it's easy to mess up the indenting when manually spacing pasted code.I just found out about C-k for indenting a block so I might give that a go though. Still the code isn't important in this case, ive already described the salient features, using asyncio queue with a put done from one sync only thread via create_task and a get from another thread that's in an async context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `create_task` from outside the thread that runs the event loop. You should use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) instead:

```py
if result:
    # tell asyncio to enqueue the result
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
        tasks.completed.put(result), loop)
    # wait for the result to be enqueued
    fut.result()
```

(You should retrieve the loop while in the main thread and pass it to the thread.)

If your queue is unbounded and you don't need to handle backpressure, you can call `put_nowait` using [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe):

```py
if result:
    # tell asyncio to enqueue the result
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(
        tasks.completed.put_nowait, result)
```

> I was able to use create_task to put the item in the queue but it's either blocking on get or put until some other async event occurs in the system before it stops blocking even though there should now be an item in the queue for it not to need to block.

This is because `loop.create_task` is not thread-safe, so it doesn't correctly notify the event loop that something has happened.

Comment: no, it's sync code it doesn't need to be awaited. the warning was from when i originally made the post, after using create_task i was able to avoid it but the problem now is the delay

Comment: @ruzq I think I spotted the actual problem, see the edited answer.